# Where exactly lies the quantum supremacy?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

What makes quantum computers faster in certain problems than normal computers? Does quantum computing means that many solutions are explored simultaneously instead of one at a time due to quantum superposition of qubits? Is the complexity of solutions explored proportional to the number of qubits?

That's my impression and my understanding of quantum computing. Any books or articles that exactly pinpoint how superposition or any other quantum phenomenon makes computation faster?

Comment: *Is the complexity of solutions explored proportional to the number of qubits?* The size of the Hilbert space for $N$ qubits is $2^N$, not $2N$. A few dozen qubits have an enormous Hilbert space.

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6198/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/8593/55 and links therein

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easiest to appreciate this through a concrete example.  One of the best (and the first) is due to Peter Shor, who sometimes frequents this site:

We would like to solve the equation
$$2^r=1 \quad (\hbox{mod } N)$$
for some large integer $N$.

First, for integers $x$ and $y$, set
$$\beta(x,y)=e^{2\pi i xy/N}$$

Now define a function of three variables
$$\alpha(a,r,y)=\sum_j\beta(a+jr,y)$$

Check that :

**(I)**
$\alpha(a,r,y)$ is large in absolute value whenever $yr/N$ is close to an integer.

**(II)**
$\alpha(a,r,y)$ is small in absolute value otherwise.

Now:

1. Prepare a register in an equally weighted superposition of $1,\ldots, N$.
2. Apply the function $x\mapsto 2^x$.   Observe the answer $y$.  Now your original register is in an equally weighted superposition of all those states $x$ such that
   $$2^x=y$$
   These states are of the form
   $$a,a+r,a+2r,\ldots$$
   where $r$ is the smallest solution to $2^r=1$.
3. Apply the function that maps $x$ to a superposition of states $y$, each with a weight $\beta(x,y)$.  The register is now in a state that is equal to any given $y$ with weight
   $$\sum_j \beta(a+jr,y)=\alpha(a,r,y)$$
4. Observe the contents of the register.  Because of **(I)** and **(II)**, your observed $y$ will probably be such that $yr/N$ is close to an integer.
5. Use the fact that $yr/N$ is close to an integer to guess at $r$.  If you don't get it in a couple of tries, go back to Step 1.

Now try to imagine how you could have mimicked this procedure in a purely classical setting.